# Tie result cannot be outputted

Tags: javascript

While creating the **rock, paper, scissors** application, I am tasked to output specific results in the console, such as outputting paper-paper and receive 'It's a tie' result. Well, I have tried to do that but for some reason, I cannot do so. The code is as below:

```js
const user = userInput => {
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if(userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors'){
    return userInput;
  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }
} 
function computer() {
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  switch(random){
    case 0 : return 'rock';
    break;
    case 1 : return 'paper';
    break;
    default : return 'scissors';
  }
};
const winner = () => {
  const choice1 = user('rock');
  const choice2 = computer();
  if(choice1 === choice2) {
    return 'It\'s a tie!';
  }
 if(choice1 === 'rock') {
  if(choice2 === 'paper') {
    return 'Computer wins!';
  } else {
    return 'You win!';
  }
}
 if(choice1 === 'paper') {
  if(choice2 === 'scissors') {
    return 'Computer wins!';
  } else {
    return 'You win!';
  }
}
 if(choice1 === 'scissors') {
  if(choice2 === 'rock') {
    return 'Computer wins!';
  } else {
    return 'You win!';
  }
}
}
console.log(winner('paper', 'paper'));
```

When I try to type console.log(winner('paper', 'paper')) for example, the result is random meaning that it can be either win, lost or tie due to the fact (or what I suppose is the reason) that the computer's choice is random but this is how I am asked to create the computer's choice. If I type console.log(('paper', 1)) I get the same result but somehow, the task is asking me to use console.log(winner('paper', 'paper')) and is telling me that the result should be a tie. I have also tried to let the user with no parameter in choice1 but I get an error due to the fact that there is no input in the user's choice.

The tasks are as below:

```js
console.log(determineWinner('paper', 'scissors')); // prints something like 'The computer won!'
console.log(determineWinner('paper', 'paper')); // prints something like 'The game is a tie!'
console.log(determineWinner('paper', 'rock')); // prints something like 'The user won!'
```

Any help or idea would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you are calling your function `winner` with two parameters but `winner()` is declared without any parameters. you need to redefine you function with something like this`winner = (userChoise, computerChoice) =>{}`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work. If It is what you need.

```js
const user = userInput => {
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if(userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors'){
    return userInput;
  } else {
    console.log('error');
  }
}
function computer() {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  switch(random){
    case 0 : return 'rock';
      break;
    case 1 : return 'paper';
      break;
    default : return 'scissors';
  }
};


// Here is where you need to change something
const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
// And use the parameters here:
  const choice1 = userChoice;
  const choice2 = computerChoice;
  if (choice1 === choice2) {
    return 'It\'s a tie!';
  }
  if (choice1 === 'rock') {
    if (choice2 === 'paper') {
      return 'Computer wins!';
    } else {
      return 'You win!';
    }
  }
  if (choice1 === 'paper') {
    if (choice2 === 'scissors') {
      return 'Computer wins!';
    } else {
      return 'You win!';
    }
  }
  if (choice1 === 'scissors') {
    if (choice2 === 'rock') {
      return 'Computer wins!';
    } else {
      return 'You win!';
    }
  }
};

const userInput = 'rock';
console.log(determineWinner(user(userInput), computer()));
console.log(determineWinner('rock', 'paper'));
console.log(determineWinner('paper', 'paper'));

// For you requirement:
console.log(determineWinner('paper', 'scissors'));
console.log(determineWinner('paper', 'paper')); 
console.log(determineWinner('paper', 'rock'));
```

But if you hardcode the parameters as you requirement suggests then your functions `user` and `computer` are not used.

Comment: Thank you! Deleting the first 2 const in winner function and creating parameters helped me finish the task.